# Android: Prevent app from being killed

Tags: java, android

I've made an Android app that plays a radio stream. It works well, low cpu and ram consumption. But if I open other apps like Facebook or even browse the internet, sometimes my radio application gets killed.

Is there a way I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: No,  It's how Android works.  You could think about a service. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Answer (score 0):

Generally no, but you have a good chance of staying alive by using a foreground service. This will show an ongoing notification, letting users know that your app is running. The system gives higher priority to those apps and they will be among the last to be killed if resources become scarce.